# How to call Microsoft Graph API using VBA?

Tags: vba, api, outlook, authorization, microsoft-graph-api

**Question**

Is it possible to call Microsoft Graph API using VBA code?

If yes, how to handle O365 authorization? I have seen plenty of topics saying to create an application in Microsoft Azure to get a token but I am surprised I must do that for a simple local use.

**What I tried**

After discovering Microsoft Graph, I tried this API in Graph Explorer
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks

I was able to create a task in planner!

Consequently, in my mind, it was possible to call this API from VBA code executed directly in Outlook.

I created this macro in Outlook:

```
Sub TaskPlannerCreation()

    Dim PlannerService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim sData As Variant

    sData = " { ""  ""planId"": ""K9Zv2QHm1U-GSAhd-PTGZfdFeOn"",""bucketId"": ""b6NVNiEIQkGZeBBzn7kWqJvAGvvs"",""title"": ""Outlook task"" } "

    With PlannerService
        .Open "POST", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "xx"
        .Send (sData)
```

I have an Authorization error with

> error code 401

**UPDATE on 12-03-2020 :**
Solution found to get a Graph Api token analysing URL when calling Graph Explorer (works perfectly for me) :

```
Function GetToken()

    Dim xml As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim urltoken As String

'copy paste the URL you see when calling Microsoft Graph Explorer and add prompt + domain_hint parameters
    urltoken = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_mode=form_post&nonce=graph_explorer&mkt=fr-FR&client_id={clientid}&response_type=token&scope=openid profile User.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All Sites.ReadWrite.All Contacts.ReadWrite People.Read Notes.ReadWrite.All Tasks.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Calendars.ReadWrite&prompt=none&domain_hint=organizations"

    xml.Open "GET", urltoken, False

    xml.Send

    If xml.readyState = 4 And xml.Status = 200 Then
        Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        doc.Body.innerHTML = xml.responseText

        GetToken = doc.getElementsByName("access_token")(0).Value

        sSuccess = True
    Else
         MsgBox "Error" & vbNewLine & "Ready state: " & xml.readyState & _
         vbNewLine & "HTTP request status: " & xml.Status
         sSuccess = False
    End If

    Set xml = Nothing

End Function
```

So using VBA for calling Graph API is possible :)

Comment: You will need to add an [Authorization header with a bearer access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?view=graph-rest-1.0).This means you'll need to implement, or find someone else's implementation ([here's a sample that uses Google auth](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/guests/oauth2)) of an OAuth client. I suggest reading this [documentation first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?view=graph-rest-1.0), and [identity documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-app-types).

Comment: I finally succeeded to get a token for Graph Api connexion using Implicit grant flow technic.
I think it can be useful for all users that have only poor knowledges like me in VBA and O365 authorization but have lot needs/ideas to improve their productivity using O365.

Answer (score 2):

So the code you show is only partially correct. Here is what I found to actually work. (This is with what you provided as I actually found a Json parser to work with the data better than the innerHTML methods, I also had to use a different version of MSXML since the one you reference wasnt working for me.)

```
Function GetToken()
    Dim xml As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim urltoken As String

    'copy paste the URL you see when calling Microsoft Graph Explorer and add prompt + domain_hint parameters
    urltoken = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenent id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"

    xml.Open "POST", urltoken, False

    xml.Send("client_id={clientid}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret=(cleint secret}")

    If xml.readyState = 4 And xml.Status = 200 Then
        Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        doc.Body.innerHTML = xml.responseText

        GetToken = doc.getElementsByName("access_token")(0).Value

        sSuccess = True
    Else
         MsgBox "Error" & vbNewLine & "Ready state: " & xml.readyState & _
         vbNewLine & "HTTP request status: " & xml.Status
         sSuccess = False
    End If

    Set xml = Nothing
End Function
```