# Access MS Graph API from VBScript

Tags: vbscript, microsoft-graph-api

It's not that high sofisticated, but i need to access the MS Graph api from VBScript on a Windows 10 client.

I've googled for days now but couldn't find a documentation or example about how to authenticate from VBScript in MS graph and then access the api.

Is this even possible?

Best regards

BoxSon

Comment: Did you find this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660322/how-to-call-microsoft-graph-api-using-vba ? It it works in VBA it is usually easy enough to get it working in vbscript.

Comment: It's a Web API so you should be able to access it via XHR. Have wrote [about this before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37462944/692942) in relation to Classic ASP (which uses VBScript).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP GET in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204759/http-get-in-vbs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the REST-based API makes it easy to communicate with MS Graph by VBScript with simple GET-Calls.