# Get Onedrive Info with API

Tags: vba, api, onedrive

I am trying to automate Onedrive link creation. I have a OneDrive folder with separate folders for each client and projects in each named in a specific way and then project files in sub folders always named the same. I want to use VBA in the end to run the code, but first I need to figure out how to get the API request to properly get my folder info. Here is an example of a path I would need to follow.

me/drive/root/Master/Client/####### - Project Name/01 - Quote Docs/

(I tried to make that as simple as I could)

I have tried using Graph Explorer but can't seem to figure out what phrasing I need to use to get it to give me the Link. I have been able to use Graph to find the client folder but it doesn't find the folders below that.

Please ask me questions of anything that can help you help me get this working. Thank you.

Comment: I have done some more messing around and was finally able to get the ID and a link to the folder. But I noticed the link was an Organizational Edit link, I would like a Anonymous View link. Is there a way to get this from just 1 request with Graph Explorer?

Comment: OK so I may have all the info I need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660322/how-to-call-microsoft-graph-api-using-vba this post had info that helped. Now I just need to work up my VBA code to do all these steps for me.

Comment: Hi @SpenserTaylorSchafer, I have several questions: What kind of link are you trying to create: a share link, or an access link for people who already have access and are logged in? A link to a folder, or to a file? Are you on Mac or on Windows? Do the receivers of the links already have access to the content, or do you want to give them access while creating the link? What information do you have to begin creating the link with... local directory path? Receiver email(s)? Did you manage to get it to work in the end? If so how?