# Chart area in MS Graph chart on MS Access 2007 is sometimes blank

Tags: vba, charts, microsoft-graph-api, ms-access-2007

I have an MS Graph XY scatter chart on a form in an MS Access 2007 database. After opening the form the chart should show immediately, but the chart only sometimes shows the graph. It seems random. The reason why the visualization of the underlying data fails to show is that the Chart Area is empty, it doesn't even show the Plot Area and the Grid Lines in it. The query underlying the chart has data in two columns.

The toolbar for the chart object shows that the chart object is aware of this, because the **in columns** icon is highlighted. Even so the chart is not showing. I can make it visible by right-clicking the chart object and then selecting **edit** and then clicking the **in rows** icon in the toolbar, followed by clicking the **in columns** icon.

The MS Access Chart Object correctly tells the MS Graph chart object that the data are in two columns. Yet MS Graph sometimes needs to be explicitly informed of this by using the toolbar for the chart.

VBA might solve this problem by performing the routine for telling the MS Graph chart object that the data are in the columns.

On the On Open Event:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.MyGraph.Object.Application.PlotBy = 1
    Me.MyGraph.Object.Application.PlotBy = 2
End Sub
```

Commentary:
PlotBy = 1 means that the data is in the rows.
PlotBy = 2 means that the data is in the columns.

This works. I'll try further if the first line of code may be eliminated without compromising the result.

Edit (2020/11/28):
After eliminating the first line of code sometimes the chart will stay blank. So it is necessary to use **both** lines of code to tell MS Graph that the series are in the columns. This makes sense, because without running the code the MS Graph interface already shows that it knows that the series are in the columns, but even then it doesn't always act upon that knowledge, which is why the chart may remain empty in the first place.
Just telling MS Graph that the series are in the columns won't wake up MS Graph. So you have to first disrupt MS Graph's knowledge of where the series are (by telling it falsely that they are in the rows) and then to tell anew where they really are.

Comment: You need to add an Authorization header with a bearer access token (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?view=graph-rest-1.0) and Identity documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: I noticed the Office 365 solutions, not the older Office tools. But i may be wrong as well. Being said that you can see the related tread that i came across - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660322/how-to-call-microsoft-graph-api-using-vba). Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Dev. MS Graph is already completely integrated in MS Access 2007. So I guess that the interface between MS Access and MS Graph has already been completely developed by the developers of MS Access. My solution was simply meant to fix a small bug in this interface. Having run this database with the fix included for a few months now I can tell you that the problem has been completely eliminated.

Comment: Great to hear!!

Answer (score 0):

- You need to add an Authorization header with a bearer access [token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?view=graph-rest-1.0) and Identity [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?view=graph-rest-1.0).
- I noticed the Office 365 solutions, not the older Office tools. But i may be wrong as well. Being said that you can see the [related tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660322/how-to-call-microsoft-graph-api-using-vba) that i came across.